# How to include angular-ui-slider into my application? (TypeError: elm.slider is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-ui-slider

What are modern instructions to include angular-ui-slider?

I did

```
bower install angular-ui-slider --save
```

then included additionally

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-slider/src/slider.js"></script>
```

and also added dependency in `app.js`

```
var pdkApp = angular.module('pdkApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'pdkControllers',
...
  'ui.slider'
]);
```

but have the following error:

```
TypeError: elm.slider is not a function
    at init (slider.js:45)
    at slider.js:54
    at angular.js:7478
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:16052)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15870)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16160)
    at done (angular.js:10589)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:10787)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10728)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you load angular.js? You need to load it before slider.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-slider/src/slider.js"></script>
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/6xta5pd0/

Comment: I do before. Where to know all such requirements?

Comment: Does it work now? You have to load jquery before you load angular.js if you specify jquery explicitly and you have to load angular.js before all other angular libs.

Comment: okay. may you can update the fiddle and reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: Trying... About your fiddle :) How are able to write so simple function as a controller? I am writing somethign long like `pdkControllers.controller('MealCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) { $scope.hourRange = [0, 24];...`

Comment: This is called 'Implicit Annotation'. Search for it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di 
If you minify your js source you will get problems with the angular dependency injection. But there are tools like ng-annotate which can help you out there.
In addition I can recommend John Papas styleguide. It's awesome:https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#minification-and-annotation